# Called function that loops depending on the argument

Tags: c, function, loops, arguments

I have a function `LED_MAIN()` whose work is to light up LEDs by calling upon another function `LED_MAIN_LINE()` which is private to it, meaning when I am testing the code I will only call `LED_MAIN()`.

```
void LED_MAIN (void)            //main function (public) to light all LEDs
{
    int i;
    int LED_NO_UP = 10 ;                 //number of LEDs on line going up
    int LED_NO_DOWN = 10;            //number of LEDs on line coming down
    void LED_MAIN_LINE ( int no );   //private function to light LEDs on either side i.e on line going up and on line coming down


    for (i=0 ; 1<20 ; i++)              //first eliminate any errors in all 20 LEDs
    {
        LED_ERROR [i] = 0;
    }

    for ( i=0 ; i<LED_NO_UP ; i++ )     //light LEDs on one side. MAX 10 LEDs. LEDs #1-10
    {
        LED_MAIN_LINE (i);
    }

    for ( i=0 ; i<LED_NO_DOWN ; i++ )   //light LEDs on the other side. LEDs #11-20
    {
        LED_MAIN_LINE (i+10);
    }
}

void LED_MAIN_LINE ( int no )   //definition of the actual LED lighting function (private to void LED_MAIN (void))
{
   //currently no reference to argument int no in this function 

    for (i = 10 ; i > 0 ; i++)
        {
            led_status [no][i] = led_status [no] [i-1]
        }
        // continued......
}
```

`LED_MAIN_LINE()` is supposed to be executed for every LED that there is. If there are 10 LEDs on either line, it will loop 20 times (10x2). If there are 5 LEDs it will only be executed 5 times & so on. The argument is the number of LEDs. However, it is being called by void `LED_MAIN()` and this is where the looping will happen.

Looking at my definition of void `LED_MAIN_LINE()` however, I have not passed an argument for the number of LEDs. I have done this in `LED_MAIN()`. I wonder, is this definition correct? Where should I pass the number of LEDs expected to make `LED_MAIN_LINE()` loop? With the current code my test results are not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

LED_NO_UP and LED_NO_DOWN are 0. So the for loops in your code are never executed because `i < 0` is not possible when `i = 0`.

Also you have `1<20` in the first for loop.

Comment: thank you for your observation. I should initialize the LED numbers to 10 though. I am correcting it. Thanks.

Comment: I missed your original question. I would suggest to take the definition of `LED_MAIN_LINE` from within `LED_MAIN` to outside and place it near the top of your file, where you define some global constants and variables.

Comment: thank you for your input. But the definition of LED_MAIN_LINE is totally outside of LED_MAIN's region as indicated by the closing curly bracket above it , } , and also the positioning (no indentation) of the statement 'void LED_MAIN_LINE ( int no )'.

Comment: Sorry, I meant function declaration. If you do not want this function to be exposed to other C files, you can also declare it as a static.