# Function that loops depending on the argument in C

Tags: c, function, arguments

I have a function LED_MAIN() whose work is to light up LEDs by calling upon another function LED_MAIN_LINE() which is private to it, meaning when I am testing the code I will only call LED_MAIN().

```
void LED_MAIN_LINE ( int no );   //private function to light LEDs on either side i.e on line going up and on line coming down 

void LED_MAIN (void)            //main function (public) to light all LEDs
{
    int i;
    int LED_NO_UP = 10 ;                 //number of LEDs on line going up
    int LED_NO_DOWN = 10;            //number of LEDs on line coming down
    int LED_ERROR[20];

    for (i=0 ; 1<20 ; i++)              //first eliminate any errors in all 20 LEDs
    {
        LED_ERROR [i] = 0;
    }

    for ( i=0 ; i<LED_NO_UP ; i++ )     //light LEDs on one side. MAX 10 LEDs. LEDs #1-10
    {
        LED_MAIN_LINE (i);
    }

    for ( i=0 ; i<LED_NO_DOWN ; i++ )   //light LEDs on the other side. LEDs #11-20
    {
        LED_MAIN_LINE (i+10);
    }
}

void LED_MAIN_LINE ( int no )   //definition of the actual LED lighting function (private to void LED_MAIN (void))
{
   //currently no reference to argument int no in this function 

    for (i = 10 ; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            led_status [no][i] = led_status [no] [i-1]
        }
        // continued......
}
```

LED_MAIN_LINE(int) is supposed to be executed for every LED that there is. If there are 10 LEDs on either line, it will loop 20 times (10x2). If there are 5 LEDs it will only be executed 5 times & so on. The argument is the number of LEDs. However, it is being called by void LED_MAIN() and this is where the looping will happen.

Looking at my definition of void LED_MAIN_LINE(int) however, I have not passed an argument for the number of LEDs. I have done this in LED_MAIN(). I wonder, is this definition correct? Where should I pass the number of LEDs expected to make LED_MAIN_LINE(int) loop? Or rather, how should I pass an argument to LED_MAIN_LINE(int)? With the current code my test results are not as expected

Comment: `for (i=0 ; 1<20 ; i++)`: 1 is always less than 20.

Comment: `for (i = 10 ; i > 0 ; i++)` I don't see any code in the body that will modify `i`, so it will eventually overflow resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Ooops, my bad! I'll correct it. I typed the wrong thing. My question still stands as I try what you've suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Do not type. Copy. Make sure that you show a [mre] which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It is because I am writing the code on a different computer, but yes, Noted. Thank you.

Comment: `int LED_ERROR[];`  should have a length or an initializer.

Comment: I don't understand this comment: **currently no reference to argument int no in this function** You have a reference in `led_status[no][i]`

Comment: @Christian Gibbons, thank you so much for your observations and input. I have made the changes but unfortunately no luck yet.

Comment: @Barmar, yes. That is where I am lost. Does that suffice as far as passing an argument is concerned? I feel like something is missing.. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You have a loop `for ( i=0 ; i<LED_NO_UP ; i++ )` that seems like it should suffice.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use all-uppercase names for functions and variables. The convention is that this is reserved for macros.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for your response & advice. I'll update if I get a solution.

Comment: **DO NOT SPAM STACK OVERFLOW** you asked this question 18 hours ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053851/called-function-that-loops-depending-on-the-argument